# MySQL: Select 3 most occuring strings either in column 1 or column 2

Tags: mysql, select, count

I'd like to have the 3 most occuring strings from 2 rows of my database. The thing is the string may occur in column1 or column2. I'd like to use only one query. Thanks in advance

Sample DB:

```
id string1 string2  
1  foo     bar  
2  bar     foo  
3  api     foo
```

Output should then be:

```
string count  
foo    3  
bar    2  
api    1
```

Comment: But that's *all* the strings!

Comment: My db is a lot bigger, the biggest count there should be more than 50 - and there's more than 3 strings ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the following query:

```
SELECT string, COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT string1 string FROM mytable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT string2 string FROM mytable
) sub
GROUP BY string
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

where `mytable` is your table name.

With this query:

- You take the union of all strings, either `string1` or `string2`.
- You group these string by their count.
- You order them by the biggest count to the lowest.
- You take only the three firsts.

Comment: this gives me three random strings from the database with a count of 1... & curious, what is the "sub" for?

Comment: `sub` is the name we give to the subquery

Comment: THANK YOU Gordon and JuniorCompressor - the UNION ALL was necessary ;) - have a good one